# Slow digitalization for Tesseract using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract to digitalize historic documents and save the text from each picture as a seperate .txt file but encountered performance problems when trying to automate the process using for loops.

When not using a for loop the process takes ~ 2.5 seconds (the code includes 'redundant' elements just to mimic the for loop):

```
test=[]
for i in tqdm(range(1)):
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Pages/3_2\\0053.jpg"), lang='dan2')
  test.append((str(text)))
  with open("test.txt", mode = 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(text))
```

However, when using a for loop it takes around 10.5 seconds for each picture:

```
n = len(listOfPages)
PagesOfText = []

for i in tqdm(range(n)):
    for entry in listOfPages:   
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(entry), lang='dan2')
        PagesOfText.append((str(text)))
    

for x in range(0,n):
    with open("page"+str(x+1)+'.txt', mode = 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(PagesOfText[x]))
```

The code yields fine results and saves a 'page{x}.txt' for each picture.

The only difference I can find, is the use of the listOfPages, which is a list of all the pictures in a directory I wish to digitalize. It has this output and includes just 4 pictures for testing:

```
print(listOfPages)
```

['C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Pages/3_2\0053.jpg', 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Pages/3_2\0053.tif', 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Pages/3_2\0055.jpg', 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Pages/3_2\0055.tif']

What I can't understand is why the act of drawing from a list could be slowing it down so much. I hope my question is fine as it is my first post. Any suggestions for the code would also be appreciated as I'm new to both Python and Tesseract.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You did not mentioned python and tesseract version, I assume python 3 and higher and tesseract 4.1. Here is code for pytesseract:

```
import datetime
import glob

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from tqdm import tqdm

# Settings
lang = "eng"
best_data = r"f:\Project-Personal\tessdata_best\tessdata"
tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "{}"'.format(best_data)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"F:\win64\bin\tesseract.exe"
listOfPages = sorted(glob.glob(r"f:\Project\tests\*.ppm"))

# OCR process
start = datetime.datetime.now()

with tqdm(total=len(listOfPages), position=0, leave=True) as pbar:
    for idx, entry in enumerate(listOfPages):
        pbar.set_description("Processing {}".format(entry))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang=lang, config=tessdata_dir_config
        )
        with open("page_t-{:03}.txt".format(idx), mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
            f.write(text)
        pbar.update(1)

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print("\nRuntime: {}".format(end - start))
```

You may try also tesserocr as it use tesseract API directly, so it should be faster:

```
import datetime
import glob

from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
from tqdm import tqdm

# Settings
lang = "eng"
best_data = r"f:\Project-Personal\tessdata_best\tessdata"
listOfPages = sorted(glob.glob(r"f:\Project\tests\*.ppm"))

# OCR process
start = datetime.datetime.now()

with tqdm(total=len(listOfPages), position=0, leave=True) as pbar:
    with PyTessBaseAPI(path=best_data, lang=lang) as api:
        for idx, entry in enumerate(listOfPages):
            pbar.set_description("Processing {}".format(entry))
            api.SetImage(Image.open(entry))
            text = api.GetUTF8Text()
            with open("page-{:03}.txt".format(idx), mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
                f.write(text)
            pbar.update(1)

end = datetime.datetime.now()
print("\nRuntime: {}".format(end - start))
```

If tesserocr is not available for your python version, you can follow instruction at this [bucket401 blog](https://bucket401.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I believe, is here:

```
for i in tqdm(range(n)):
    for entry in listOfPages:
        parse_page(entry)
```

You are looping twice over the pages: the `for i in tqdm(range(n))` loops `n` times and the `for entry in listOfPages` loops again `n` times per each value of `i`. Just one of the two loops is sufficient.

**Edit**:

If you want to show the progress bar, you can just wrap any `iterable` in `tqdm` like so, it will take care of it automatically:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

ll = ["any", "iterable", "you", "want"]

for el in tqdm(ll):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well spotted! How would you implement the 'tqdm' progress bar without affecting the number of loops done?

Comment: @DruttiFrutti I edited the answer to show how to do that.